# Passing database data through anchor tag in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am using a table inside a repeater. Basically I want to pass to pass the Data from the SQL Data Source and pass it to a function at the server side using anchor tag.

```
        <td>
            <%# Eval("Quantity")%>+ in stock<br />
            <input class="textbox" maxlength="2" name="Quantity" size="2" type="text" 
                value="1" />
                <br />

                         <div class="buttons">
                            <a id="A1" class="positive" runat="server" onserverclick="addtocart(<%# Eval("ProductDescriptionId")%>,<%# Eval("Quantity")%>
                                Add to Cart
                            </a>
                            </div>
```

It is this particular hyperlink where I want to pass the parameters.

```
<a id="A1" class="positive" runat="server" onserverclick="addtocart(<%# Eval("ProductDescriptionId")%>,<%# Eval("Quantity")%>Add to Cart</a>
```

Comment: What's rendered now? It looks like the link is malformatted.

Comment: yes it is malformatted. The server tag is not formed well.

Comment: You're missing the `)">` at the end of the link

Comment: can you just try like this onserverclick="addtocart(<%# Eval('ProductDescriptionId')%>,<%# Eval('Quantity')%>)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link should probably look like this:

```
<a id="A1" 
     class="positive" 
     runat="server" 
     onserverclick='addtocart(<%# Eval("ProductDescriptionId")%>,<%# Eval("Quantity")%>)'>
  Add to Cart
</a>
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo..the server tag is not formed well....which means something is wrong

Comment: In that case, I think it is because you enclose the expression in `"` while the expression itself contains `"`. That is usually a problem. Use `'` to enclose the expression instead.

Comment: im getting this error
CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Comment: Are you using a DataBound control? You cannot use `<%# .. %>` unless you are inside the `ItemTemplate` of a DataBound control such as the `Repeater` or the `GridView`.